# How to squircle an app icon image with just CSS

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to use [The Code Player's CSS3 Squircles example](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-squircles) to create an iOS-7-style app icon on my website (testing in the Safari browser). The example uses pseudo tags to clip the background color, whereas I need to crop around an `<img>`. In case you're not familiar, a [squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle) is like a rounded-rect, but with the sides rounding beyond the corner radius, like so:

[image: a squircle]

```css
.icons img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  border-radius: 24%;
}

.icons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
/*Now we will create fish-eye shapes using pseudo elements and clip them to add a curve to the sides of the icons*/
.icons a:before, .icons a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 100%; /*circle*/
  /*time to transform the circle into fish-eye shape. iOS7 style now.*/
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(1.05);
  transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(1.05);
  /*clipping the left and right sides - 17px from the left and right*/
  clip: rect(0, 66px, 100px, 34px);
  /*pushing it behind the icon*/
  z-index: -1;
}
/*duplicating the :before element and rotating it 90deg and swapping the X/Y transforms*/
.icons a:after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(2) scaleX(1.05) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/256/256/abstract/2/" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Increase the border-radius?  Eventually, you get a circle.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I'm trying to make a "squircle", not a circle. I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: One way is clip-path [link] https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: I don't know what the problem is with creating some round-cornered div tag and placing an image inside.  Works just fine with ios.  If you want the corners a bit more rounded, I will agree with @jmargolisvt, just increase the border-radius.

Comment: https://pavellaptev.medium.com/squircles-on-the-web-houdini-to-the-rescue-5ef11f646b72

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to create the image with a transparent background until some of the following features are implemented.

If you can add the image via CSS then you could just add height, width, background-image and background-size to the link (`.icons a`).

**Note:** This might not be the desired effect as it is complemented by a background colour.

```css
.icons a {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/256/);
      background-size: cover;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 20px;
      border-radius: 24px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .icons a:before,
    .icons a:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: inherit;
      border-radius: 100%;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(1.05);
      transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(1.05);
      clip: rect(0, 66px, 100px, 34px);
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .icons a:after {
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(2) scaleX(1.05) rotate(90deg);
      transform: scaleY(2) scaleX(1.05) rotate(90deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="icons">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

If this is not the case you could add size and border radius to the image. In this case the the pseudo rounded borders are filled by a background colour on the '.icon a' element.

**Note:** This might not be the desired effect as it is complemented by a background colour.

```css
.icons a {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background: red;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 20px;
      border-radius: 24px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .icons img{
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border-radius: 24px;
    }
    .icons a:before, .icons a:after {
      content: '';
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
      width: 100%; height: 100%;
      background: inherit;
      border-radius: 100%;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(1.05);
      transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(1.05);
      clip: rect(0, 66px, 100px, 34px);
      z-index: -1;
    }
    .icons a:after {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(2) scaleX(1.05) rotate(90deg);
        transform: scaleY(2) scaleX(1.05) rotate(90deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="icons">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/256/">
    </a>
</div>
```

**SVG Solution 1:**
Use a cliping-path using an svg but this is not yet supported by webkit (sticks the clipped image at the top left of the screen). See this link for more info: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#comment-1587234

```css
#squircle{  
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svg-shape);
  -moz-clip-path: url(#svg-shape);
  -o-clip-path: url(#svg-shape);
  -ms-clip-path: url(#svg-shape);
  clip-path: url(#svg-shape);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/" id="squircle">

<svg height="0" width="0" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
  <clipPath id="svg-shape">
<path d="M100,200c43.8,0,68.2,0,84.1-15.9C200,168.2,200,143.8,200,100s0-68.2-15.9-84.1C168.2,0,143.8,0,100,0S31.8,0,15.9,15.9C0,31.8,0,56.2,0,100s0,68.2,15.9,84.1C31.8,200,56.2,200,100,200z" />
    </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**SVG Solution 2:**
Use a pattern to add the image as a background image.

```css
svg.iOS-svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="iOS-svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="squircle" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="200">
        <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/256/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

    <path d="M100,200c43.8,0,68.2,0,84.1-15.9C200,168.2,200,143.8,200,100s0-68.2-15.9-84.1C168.2,0,143.8,0,100,0S31.8,0,15.9,15.9C0,31.8,0,56.2,0,100s0,68.2,15.9,84.1C31.8,200,56.2,200,100,200z" fill="url(#squircle)" />
</svg>
```

**Other Resources:**
http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path (Partial support at time of writing)
SVG support: http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: They both work in Chrome. The first one works in Safari, with `-webkit-transform`, but the second won't (and I'd prefer to keep the image's source specified in the HTML. Are there any other webkit-specific extensions to get that one to work in Safari?

Comment: Instead of replacing it I would add the `-webkit` rule above the plain `transform` as it would act as a fallback when the browser is not webkit based. You might want to add an `-ms` rule for IE9 and a `-moz` for firefox too. Other rules that you might want to add prefixes to: `border-radius` and `background-size` although many browsers now support them. This link might give you a better idea of cross browser selectors and how to use autoprefixer if you use sass: [link](https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/) and this one is to check if what browsers support css3 rules [link](http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: Actually, the second example is cheating a bit, since the dummy image I chose for this post happens to be black. If you set the `background` of `.icons a` to `blue`, then you'll see it's not using the ellipses to crop the image.

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that as I wasn't sure what the real use was. Do you depend on the img tag being present?

Comment: I updated your answer with the webkit extensions, and a new sample image that's multicolored. I don't "depend" on the `img` tag, but I prefer specifying image assets in the HTML whenever possible. If there's no easy way to accomplish it, I will definitely use your first example, since it does work.

Comment: After more carefully choosing a sample image, the first example isn't 100% there either, as the "circle" part that extends out behind is the image rotated 90 degrees. Can you see it?

Comment: Updated the answer with a few extra options although they might not be fully supported by all browsers yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91644/discussion-between-dov-and-diego).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.squircle {
  width: 52.1em;
  height: 52.1em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
.squircle > * {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background: 50% 50% no-repeat;
  z-index: 5;
}
.squircle:before,
.squircle:after,
.squircle > *:before,
.squircle > *:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #00aeef;
}
.squircle:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 4em;
  border-top-left-radius: 20em 10em;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20em 10em;
  content: "";
}
.squircle:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 4em;
  border-top-left-radius: 80% 10em;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80% 10em;
  content: "";
}
.squircle:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 4em;
  border-top-right-radius: 80% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80% 20%;
  width: 25em;
  content: "";
}
.squircle > *:before {
  top: 4em;
  bottom: 4em;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 10em;
  content: "";
}
.squircle > *:after {
  top: 4em;
  bottom: 4em;
  right: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 10em;
  content: "";
  z-index: 4;
}
body {
  background: #1F1A1D;
}
body::before {
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="squircle">
  <span>I'm a squircle!</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A squircle is **not** `border-radius` or round corners, and you must draw the path by yourself.
[image]

The article from figma's blog and their implementation in Github.

https://www.figma.com/blog/desperately-seeking-squircles/
https://github.com/MartinRGB/Figma_Squircles_Approximation

Answer (score -1):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="470px" height="468px" viewBox="0 0 470 468" version="1.1">
  <path fill="#987EFC" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.635 132.808C24.782 59.782 71.388 19.109 144.085 6.822c53.74-9.081 107.5-9.196 161.15.255 74.852 13.185 119.85 56.23 134.185 130.36 11.075 57.29 11.249 115.191-.174 172.427-15.324 72.52-63.132 117.285-135.561 129.527-53.74 9.08-107.5 9.195-161.15-.255-74.852-13.186-120.05-58.38-134.384-132.509-11.64-57.668-10.52-115.935 1.484-173.82z" id="path-1"/>
  </svg>
```