# svg fill image quality. How to fix?

Tags: image, svg, fill

I have patterns that each have a single image in them.

I have not used svgs much before and do not know which attributes to change to get clear result. I've been trying all sorts of combinations of preserveAspectRatio, viewBox,  patternUnits, but I cannot seem to get what I want.

https://codepen.io/shkasjon/pen/WYwZmy
here you can see that the second svg image is displayed clearly and sharply and the first one is blurred.

How can i fix the quality of the first svg image?

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="146" height="146" viewBox="-10 -10 470 468">
    <defs><pattern id="image-as_profile_widget-4" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"><image itemprop="photo" height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4a7131ab3b3fa22f2fea9fadaa018981?s=146"></image></pattern></defs><path fill="url(#image-as_profile_widget-4)" d="M9.635 132.808C24.782 59.782 71.388 19.109 144.085 6.822c53.74-9.081 107.5-9.196 161.15.255 74.852 13.185 119.85 56.23 134.185 130.36 11.075 57.29 11.249 115.191-.174 172.427-15.324 72.52-63.132 117.285-135.561 129.527-53.74 9.08-107.5 9.195-161.15-.255-74.852-13.186-120.05-58.38-134.384-132.509-11.64-57.668-10.52-115.935 1.484-173.82z" id="path-1"></path></svg>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="146" height="146" viewBox="-10 -10 146 146">
    <defs><pattern id="image-as_profile_widget-2" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"><image itemprop="photo" height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4a7131ab3b3fa22f2fea9fadaa018981?s=146"></image></pattern></defs>    
    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="4" ry="4" width="146" height="146" fill="url(#image-as_profile_widget-2)" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" id="path-1"></rect>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Why are you using svg in this purpose? Why not just apply styling in an <img> element?

Comment: I need Squircle shape. in css it`s impossible as i know

Comment: Did you read this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979585/how-to-squircle-an-app-icon-image-with-just-css

Comment: patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" add this to <pattern> not the best but better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" add to `<pattern >`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="146" height="146" viewBox="-10 -10 470 468">
<defs><pattern id="image-as_profile_widget-4" height="100%" width="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"><image itemprop="photo" height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4a7131ab3b3fa22f2fea9fadaa018981?s=146"></image></pattern></defs><path fill="url(#image-as_profile_widget-4)" d="M9.635 132.808C24.782 59.782 71.388 19.109 144.085 6.822c53.74-9.081 107.5-9.196 161.15.255 74.852 13.185 119.85 56.23 134.185 130.36 11.075 57.29 11.249 115.191-.174 172.427-15.324 72.52-63.132 117.285-135.561 129.527-53.74 9.08-107.5 9.195-161.15-.255-74.852-13.186-120.05-58.38-134.384-132.509-11.64-57.668-10.52-115.935 1.484-173.82z" id="path-1"></path></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="146" height="146" viewBox="-10 -10 146 146">
<defs><pattern id="image-as_profile_widget-2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"><image itemprop="photo" height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4a7131ab3b3fa22f2fea9fadaa018981?s=146"></image></pattern></defs>    
<rect x="0" y="0" rx="4" ry="4" width="146" height="146" fill="url(#image-as_profile_widget-2)" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" id="path-1"></rect>
```